# Move folder contents to other directory containing same hierarchy

Tags: command-line, bash

This is source path  /Archive/testing/   there are three folders AB1 and AB2 and AB3.

This is destination directory  /RXB2Bi_Archive/Archive_testing123/  there are three folders AB1 and AB2 and AB3

We want to move the files from source to destination with single command.(AB1 folders files AB1 folder…etc)

We are trying this command.. but it was moved all the files to /RXB2Bi_Archive/Archive_testing123/  not moved to AB1 and AB2 and AB3

```
#!/bin/bash
Find  /Archive/testing/   / -type f -mtime +190 -exec mv '{}' /RXB2Bi_Archive/Archive_testing123/ \;

……………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………….
Source: /Archive/testing/              Destination: /RXB2Bi_Archive/Archive_testing123/  

AB1 folder                                              AB1 folder   
AB2 folder                                              AB2 folder
AB3 folder                                              AB3 folder

……………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………….......................
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use rysnc:

```
rsync -avz Archive/testing/ RXB2Bi_Archive/Archive_testing123/
```

Example:

```
mkdir -p Archive/testing/AB{1..3}

touch Archive/testing/AB{1..3}/sourceFiles
```

Let's see the result:

```
$ tree
.
└── Archive
    └── testing
        ├── AB1
        │   └── sourceFiles
        ├── AB2
        │   └── sourceFiles
        └── AB3
            └── sourceFiles

5 directories, 3 files
```

Now let's create the destination:

```
mkdir -p RXB2Bi_Archive/Archive_testing123/AB{1..3}

touch RXB2Bi_Archive/Archive_testing123/AB{1..3}/destFiles
```

let's check result:

```
$ tree

RXB2Bi_Archive/
└── Archive_testing123
    ├── AB1
    │   └── destFiles
    ├── AB2
    │   └── destFiles
    └── AB3
        └── destFiles

4 directories, 3 files
```

Now run the command:

```
$ rsync -avz Archive/testing/ RXB2Bi_Archive/Archive_testing123/
sending incremental file list
./
AB1/
AB1/sourceFiles
AB2/
AB2/sourceFiles
AB3/
AB3/sourceFiles

sent 268 bytes  received 84 bytes  704.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

check result:

```
$ tree RXB2Bi_Archive/
RXB2Bi_Archive/
└── Archive_testing123
    ├── AB1
    │   ├── destFiles
    │   └── sourceFiles
    ├── AB2
    │   ├── destFiles
    │   └── sourceFiles
    └── AB3
        ├── destFiles
        └── sourceFiles

4 directories, 6 files
```

As you see above all files is copied to its needed place in the destination.

Comment: Can I use the below command to move files which are older than 1 monthrsync.                                                                                               -avz Archive/testing/ -type f -mtime +30 -exec mv '{}' RXB2Bi_Archive/Archive_testing123/ \;